# How to remove an entire row when any of the cells contains a specific value or string?

Tags: powerquery

I have a table in Power Query that loads with an unknown number of columns and rows. In all this data, there is a specific cell that will contain the text "item sum". I want to know how to remove the entire row of data that contains the text "item sum"

Hence in below example, row 133 would be removed from the table

[image]

Comment: Please share your sample data and expected results.

Comment: Done. Have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to add a column that checks for the text, then filter on that column

add column .. custom column ... with

```
= List.Sum(List.Transform(Record.FieldValues(_), each try if Text.Contains(_,"Item sum") then 1 else 0 otherwise 0))
```

then use arrow atop that new column to uncheck the 1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Sum(List.Transform(Record.FieldValues(_), each try if Text.Contains(_,"Item sum") then 1 else 0 otherwise 0))),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Custom] <>1)
in  #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: I've made a small edit so that this will not error out in case of blank cells